# Is it possible to return MAX(date) only if MAX(date) is a year in the past?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to have a list of items that haven't shipped in the past 12 months.
And this is where I am at so far.

```
SELECT 
    i.part                    AS "Part Number",
    count(distinct i.item_id) AS "Quantity",
    t.transaction_code        AS "Type of Issue",
    MAX(t.created_on)         AS "Last Issue Date"
FROM
         Table1 i
    JOIN Table2 t ON t.part = i.part
WHERE
    t.transaction_code IN ( 'XX1', 'XX2', 'XX3', 'XX4', 'XX5' )
    AND i.segregation_code NOT IN ( 'YY1', 'YY2', 'YY3', 'YY4' )
GROUP BY
    i.part,
    t.transaction_code,
    t.created_on
ORDER BY
    t.created_on desc,
    i.part;
```

Since I can't include MAX() in the where clause what are my options?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT 
    i.part                    AS "Part Number",
    count(distinct i.item_id) AS "Quantity",
    t.transaction_code        AS "Type of Issue",
    MAX(t.created_on)         AS "Last Issue Date"
FROM
         Table1 i
    JOIN Table2 t ON t.part = i.part
WHERE
    t.transaction_code IN ( 'XX1', 'XX2', 'XX3', 'XX4', 'XX5' )
    AND i.segregation_code NOT IN ( 'YY1', 'YY2', 'YY3', 'YY4' )
GROUP BY
    i.part,
    t.transaction_code,
    t.created_on
HAVING
    MAX(t.created_on) <= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)
ORDER BY
    t.created_on desc,
    i.part;
```

Comment: @user21392923 don't forget to mark the question as answered :-)